# I belong to shia sect so as per our islamic teachings want to get an answer

Tags: halal-haram

Can we refer someone to a bank personnel to open their bank account and get commission because my understanding for commission to be halal is there has to be a product involved, for eg customers from high risk countries like Africa sudan etc cannot open account easily but to open the account they are ok to pay commission which can take lot of approvals and time to open their accounts